# NameError (uninitialized constant Rake::EarlyTime):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added a new gem for new relic in my rails application and after installing it,
when i start my server in local for development it works fine.

But after making some changes in the controller and trying to re-run the application, it shows an error like below

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Rake::EarlyTime):
  rake (10.1.0) lib/rake/ext/time.rb:9:in `<=>'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:100:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:100:in `max'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:100:in `updated_at'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:66:in `updated?'
```

Comment: can you add the file as it was before and after the changes to your original post?

Comment: Actually its only one modification i just commented one line and enabled another line.. this line actually calls methods of 2 different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

I tried disabling the new relic gem in Gemfile and this solved my issue.

Not sure about the real cause of this issue.